# Extending Query Statement to Include Users Following

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that I am getting post from a database. I have a 3 table join to get posts, profile picture, and user names. The current query is below.

```
 SELECT Posts.*, Profiles.ProfilePhoto, Users.Name, Users.Username
 FROM ((Posts
 INNER JOIN Profiles ON Posts.UserID = Profiles.UserID)
 INNER JOIN Users ON Posts.UserID = Users.ID)
 WHERE Posts.UserID = ? 
 ORDER BY Posts.CreateDate DESC
```

Right now I am getting the data from the user's posts (where posts.userID = ?). But i wanted to extend the query to also get the posts from users that the he/she follows.

That would need me adding something like another inner join like

```
INNER JOIN Follow ON Posts.UserID = Follow.Followed (WHERE Follow.Follower = ?) // ? being $userID;
```

But that isn't going to work because you can't throw that WHERE statement to the end of the inner join. So I was wondering what the most efficient way to add that into the current query would be?

Comment: Focus on finding *a way*, then work out how to make it more efficient

Comment: On rows showing the posts from users that the target userId follows, what should be in `Profiles.ProfilePhoto, Users.Name, Users.Username` columns?  The target UserId's profile/user/username or the users who posted the posts?

Comment: @kc2018 exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use a left join instead of an inner join, it might work

your left join would be something like

```
left join follow 
on posts.userid=follow.follwed
and follow.follower=?
```

be careful, though, because when you add that extra join it could give you extra rows (depending on how many rows you get from follow)

without seeing the diagram it is hard to say for sure

another way would do it would be maybe something like this?

```
WHERE (posts.userid=?
OR posts.userid in (select followed from follow
                    where follower=?))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.. I always forget about the IN